# Объединение нескольких текстовых файлов txt построчно c редактированием значений

Tags: c#

Необходимо объединить несколько файлов (3-10) в один построчно, при этом к с возможностью взаимодействия со строками.

2-3 файла еще можно обойти, но если их будет больше 10 цикл будет слишком большой. Подскажите, как лучше сделать.

```
using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText("10.txt"))
{
    using (StreamReader sr1 = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.Default))
    {
        using (StreamReader sr2 = new StreamReader(path, Encoding.Default))
        {
            string line1 = null;
            string line2 = null;
            while ((line1 = sr1.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                line1 = line1 + " sr1";
                writer.WriteLine(line1);
                line2 = sr2.ReadLine();
                if (line2 != null)
                {
                    line2 = line2 + " sr2";
                    writer.WriteLine(line2);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Пример:

Есть несколько файлов (может быть больше) txt c 50 строками в каждом

- первый.txt
- 1
- 1
- и так далее...
- 
- второй.txt
- 2
- 2
- и так далее...
- 
- третий.txt
- 3
- 3
- и так далее...

Объединить построчно   в 1 файл txt, берем по 1 значению из каждого файла по порядку

- 1 (первая строка из первого)
- 2 (первая строка из второго)
- 3 (первая строка из третьего)
- 1 (вторая строка из первого)
- 2 (вторая строка из второго)
- 3 (второая строка из третьего)
- и так далее...

При этом в коде иметь доступ к дополнительному редактированию строк: К строкам из первого файла добить значение одной переменной (АА), К строкам из второго файла другой переменной (ББ) и так далее. Чтобы в итоге получилось

- 1АА
- 2ББ
- 3ВВ
- 1АА
- 2ББ
- 3ВВ
- и так далее...

Comment: Есть несколько файлов txt c строками 1,1,1,1 2,2,2,2 3,3,3,3, Объединить построчно 1,2,3,1,2,3, при этом в коде иметь доступ к дополнительному редактированию строк: К строкам 1,1,1 добить значение одной переменной, К строкам 2,2,2 другой переменной.

Comment: *Объединить построчно* Вы правда думаете, что из этой хрени можно что-то понять? Любая цифирь в показанном результате - вот блин из какого файла она? почему попала на именно это место? Почему из 12 значений (4 файла по 3 значения) в результат попали только 6? Почему в нужном результате с "добитыми символами" не те значения, что в результате без "добития"? *несколько файлов txt c строками* Это одна строка с 3 значениями, или надо понимать что в файле 3 строки, на каждой одна цифра?

Comment: Попробовал объяснить понятнее

Comment: Ну тогда это не вложенные циклы. Открываете все файлы, а потом один цикл while. В нём вычитываете из каждого файла одну строку, если строка есть (файл не кончился), довешиваете что надо для именно этого файла, сбрасываете результат в выходной файл. Как прошли по всем файлам, сбросили по одной строке - пошёл новый виток цикла. И так пока на очередном витке все файлы не покажут дно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var files = new string[] { "a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt" };
var values = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };

if (files.Length != values.Length)
    throw new IndexOutOfRangeException("Arrays lengths do not match");

var enumerators = new List<IEnumerator<string>>();

foreach (var file in files)
    enumerators.Add(File.ReadLines(file).GetEnumerator());

int counter;
do
{
    counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < enumerators.Count; i++)
    {
        if (enumerators[i].MoveNext())
            Console.WriteLine(enumerators[i].Current + values[i]);
        else
            counter++;
    }
} while (counter < enumerators.Count);

foreach (var enumerator in enumerators)
    enumerator.Dispose();
```

В массиве `files` - имена файлов.
В массиве `values` - значения, которые добавляем к строкам файлов.
Размеры этих массивов должны совпадать.

Открываем файлы на чтение и получаем перечислители (энумераторы), которые заносим в список.

Далее поочерёдно берём значения из энумераторов и присоединяем к ним соответсвующие значения из массива.

Счётчик `counter` содержит количество неактивных энумераторов, в которых закончились значения.

Количество строк в файлах может быть разным. Если оно во всех файлах одинаковое, то код можно упростить, избавившись от счётчика.

В конце освобождаем ресурсы.

Comment: Linq `Zip(Zip)` бы подошло еще, наверное.

Answer (score 0):

Схематично (no syntax):

```
open file1;
open file2;
...
open fileN;
open outfile;
do 
    flag=0;
    tmp=readline(file1);
    if (tmp != null)
        outfile.write(tmp + "addition for file1");
        flag=1;
    tmp=readline(file2);
    if (tmp != null)
        outfile.write(tmp + "addition for file2");
        flag=1;
    ...
    tmp=readline(fileN);
    if (tmp != null)
        outfile.write(tmp + "addition for fileN");
        flag=1;
while (flag=1);
close all;
```